# Initializing class constant in constructor in PHP

Tags: php

Just like in C++ is it possible to initialize class constant in the constructor?

Similar to C++ it'd look like:

```
class Abc
{
    const WIDTH;

    public __constructor($width):WIDTH($width) //WIDTH gets assigned here and is immutable
    {
        //I know syntax may not be ok but is anything similar possible in PHP?
    }

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, this is not possible in PHP.  A constant's value must be defined when you define the constant, and it must be a constant expression.

**Not recommended:** Of course, if [runkit](http://php.net/runkit) is installed, you can use [`runkit_constant_add()`](http://php.net/runkit_constant_add):

```
public function __construct($width)
{
    runkit_constant_add(__CLASS__ . '::WIDTH', $width);
}
```